# getElementsByClassName() failed in my VBA

Tags: vba, getelementsbyclassname

contents in Webpage as follow:

```
<pre>
<div class="catdivlogo">
<img src="//static.designandreuse.com/sip/logo/rambus2.gif" border="0" class="catlogo" alt="Rambus, Inc.">          
</div>
</pre>
```

I failed to get the middle line by `.getElementsByClASSnAME("catlogo")`. I can only get the first line by `.getElementsByClASSnAME("catlogo")`.

Anybody can help this?


My VBA as follow:

```
Sub Test()
Const URL As String = "https://www.design-reuse.com/sip/pci-express-c-430/"
Const CLASS_NAME As String = "catlogo"
Dim oDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim results As Object

With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHttp")
.Open "GET", URL, False
.send
'Check the response is valid
 If .Status = 200 Then
  Set oDoc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
  oDoc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
  Set results = oDoc.getElementsByClassName(CLASS_NAME)
 End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an array (more than one element) - so you need to select the first one: `getElementsByClassName(CLASS_NAME)(0)` - but it will error if none are found.

Comment: You have the wrong class from what I see. The class is "logo". You then need to loop the returned collection and index into it.